# Почему когда я вывожу данные с БД они выводятся не корректно Django Mysql

Tags: python, django-orm

У меня проблема в том, что когда мне нужно вывести данные из БД, но там есть html коды тоже. То в шаблоне они отражаются как строка а не вид ну типо `<h1>` заголовок -

## Вот так

, но вместо заголовка там `<h1>Текст</h1>`

Мой код в **views.py**:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from text.models import Doc

def index(request, idt):
    posts = {'posts': Doc.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' + str(idt)), 'link': Doc.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM text_sidenav WHERE post_id = ' + str(idt))}
    return render(request, 'main/mainT/doc.html', posts)
```

код в **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from main.models import AccountsQ

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:idt>', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

сам шаблон:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      {% for post in posts %}
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="text-center">{{post.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
  {{post.text}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/ref/templates/language.html#automatic-html-escaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение, просто к коду, например:

```
{{post.title}}
```

добавьте **| safe**:

```
{{post.title | safe}}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в БД у вас вместо "<" и ">" хранится "& l t ;" и "& g t ;"

А строка из вашего кода:

```
<h3 class="text-center">{{post.title}}</h3>
```

наверняка правильно отображается.

Comment: Да вы правы, благодарю, только наоборот, у меня в БД все правильно а выводилось с этими символами. И чтобы исправить это надо было добавить safe| {{safe | post.title}}